# Using regex to match a pattern in the middle of a string with awk, sed, grep ... something linux-y

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file with ID numbers and a bunch of patterns that represent gene trees 
ex:

```
021557  (sfra,(pdep,snud),((spal,sint),(sdro,(hpul,(sprp,afra)))));
005852  (snud,sfra,(pdep,(hpul,((afra,sprp),(sint,(spal,sdro))))));
023685  (sfra,snud,(pdep,(hpul,((sprp,(afra,spal)),(sdro,sint)))));
022020  (sfra,snud,(pdep,(hpul,(afra,(sprp,(sdro,(sint,spal)))))));
028284  (sfra,snud,(pdep,(hpul,(sprp,((sdro,sint),(spal,afra))))));
```

I am interested in a certain sister taxon grouping of (spal,afra).I want to print the IDs from another column if the tree contains (spal,afra).

Output if it was only run on the data above should be:
023685
028284

I was going to do something like:

```
awk '{if ($2 == "(spal,afra)") { print $1 } }'
```

but I realize that the part that I'm trying to match is within a bunch of other characters, and at no predictable location...

So I need to search for

1. any number of lowercase letters or  parentheses or commas
2. (spal,afra)
3. any number of lowercase letters or  parentheses or commas or ;

Also, I guess I want to know of occurences in the other order (afra,spal). But I was going to run separate matches, combine the output and do something with sort and uniq-c if I remember right... I can probably figure that out by myself later.

I'm kind of new to this and I've already spent a couple of hours trying to figure something out. Thank you!

Comment: `[a-z(),]*(\(spal,afra\))[a-z(),;]*`

Comment: Is the ID something that is in the string? If not, why can't you just search for `\(spal,afra\)`  as a substring without doing anything else? Or is it something like `\(spal,[a-z(),]*afra` ? where there is separation?

Comment: Is this with awk, or a different command? I'm trying to figure out how to get it as part of a working if statement.

Comment: `the file` - Do you mean with multiple lines?

Comment: I actually have a file that is tab delimited. 2 columns: one with ID numbers, the second with these tree things. Probably 5000 rows to search through

Comment: Show sample data from file with your expected output

Comment: Looks to be a simple grep. Need the sample line in _full_ to get the ID and the other part.

Comment: Incorporate that sample into your post.

Comment: Sorry, first post ever. Give me a sec to figure out how to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have this as an input file

```
$ cat file
021557  (sfra,(pdep,snud),((spal,sint),(sdro,(hpul,(sprp,afra)))));
005852  (snud,sfra,(pdep,(hpul,((afra,sprp),(sint,(spal,sdro))))));
023685  (sfra,snud,(pdep,(hpul,((sprp,(afra,spal)),(sdro,sint)))));
022020  (sfra,snud,(pdep,(hpul,(afra,(sprp,(sdro,(sint,spal)))))));
028284  (sfra,snud,(pdep,(hpul,(sprp,((sdro,sint),(spal,afra))))));
```

#### Using awk

To print the first column for any line that contains `(spal,afra)`:

```
$ awk '/[(]spal,afra[)]/{print $1}' file
028284
```

The condition `/[(]spal,afra[)]/` selects lines that contain `(spal,afra)` and `print $1` prints the first field on those lines.

In awk regular expressions, parens are active characters.  Since we want to match literal parens, we put them in square brackets like `[(]` and `[)]`.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -n '/(spal,afra)/ s/\t.*//p' file
028284
```

`sed -n` will not print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.  `/(spal,afra)/` selects lines containing `(spal,afra)`.  `s/\t.*//p` removes everything after the first tab and then prints what remains.

By default, sed uses basic regular expressions.  This means that `(` and `)` are *not* active.  Consequently, we do not need to escape them.

#### Using grep and cut

```
$ grep '(spal,afra)' file | cut -f1
028284
```

`grep '(spal,afra)' file` selects lines that contain `(spal,afra)` and `cut -f1` selects the first field from those lines.

Like sed, grep defaults to using basic regular expressions.  This means that `(` and `)` are both treated as literal characters and there is no need to escape them.

#### Alternative:  Looking for either `(spal,afra)` or `(afra,spal)`

If we want to look for `(afra,spal)` in addition to `(spal,afra)`, then we need to update the regular expressions.  Taking awk for example:

```
awk '/[(](spal,afra|afra,spal)[)]/{print $1}' file2
023685
028284
```

Here, the vertical bar, `|`, separates choices.  The regex accepts either what is before or after the bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this non-regex search in awk:

```
awk 'index($0, "(spal,afra)") || index($0, "(afra,spal)") {print $1}' file
023685
028284
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (sed with extended regex):

```
sed -nr 's/([^[:space:]]*)[^;]*(\(spal,afra\)|\(afra,spal\)).*/\1/p' file
```

Output:

```
023685
028284
```